# Git Notifications on Pull/Submodule Update

Tags: mysql, git, go, git-commit, git-pull

I'm currently on a dev team building a website using MySql, Go, and a customized templating engine for the front-end.  We use Git for version control.

As I edit the model structs, I occasionally have to make breaking changes to the db structure (we're still early in the process here).  We construct our schema in the Go code, so all I need to do is drop my database and the app will recreate a new one on startup, with the correct structure.

However, my teammates aren't necessarily aware of these breaking changes to the db.  They do a pull or a submodule update, and most things may work fine, but when they move to a particular section of the site or use a particular feature they get strange databases errors (go figure, right?).

I'd like to have some way to notify my teammates that the db structure has changed, and that they need to rebuild it.  I can obviously put that information into a commit message, but then they need to inspect the log after every pull.

Is there any way to make a message show up in the console when a user pulls/submodule updates/checks out a particular commit?

Comment: You might be able to use a post-merge hook to take care of this automatically

Comment: If your db can be rebuilt by the app, why it is versionned ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: @FélixCantournet The App doesn't rebuild the DB every time you launch it; only if the DB exists but is missing the tables. Therefore if you commit changes to the schema/structs that conflict with what currently exists in the DB, you need to drop & recreate it to allow the App to rebuild the tables in the new, correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You could, as suggested, use a `post-merge` hook but:

- it needs to be deployed on all client
- it won't execute if the pull resulted in any conflict

A centralized approach might be best, where you have:

- a versioned script able to rebuild the db, and to create a new commit with message "`DB Vxxx rebuilt`"
- a versioned file with "`Vxxx`" in it to memorize or detect that the version of the db has changed
- a unique `pre-receive` hook on the Git repositories hosting server used by all the developers rejecting their commits if none of the commit pushed include "`DB Vxxx rebuilt`" message, with a matching the content (`git show`) of the file storing the official db version.

That way, a developer would have to be sure his/her history includes a trace of the DB having been rebuilt, with a version matching the one stored by the last person having modified said db structure.

Comment: I think this is not quite what I'm looking for. The goal is that when a user pulls, he gets a message. In your suggestion, you prevent the user from pushing up to origin unless he puts a specific string in his commit message. That's fine, but the goal is to notify the dev that, since he just pulled/checked out a certain commit, he needs to rebuild his DB. Make sense?

Comment: @MattMc it does. My suggestion is more about getting that message on the push.